# unique identifier for solaris volume

Tags: solaris, filesystems, disk-volume

How to get a unique identifier UUID for a solaris volume meta device?  I want the unique id like RID in veritas volume manager in solaris.

Comment: Are you talking about DiskSuite or ZFS?  What operations do you want to use it for?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Solaris has support for UUIDs on volumes. It has the `makeuuid` command but it only generates UUIDs.